# Add imageview above tabs implemented using view pager

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I am creating horizontal tab using page viewer.In my main.xml I am setting header and page viewer and in my fragment.xml I am defining table layout.

My main.xml-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/header1" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="#fff" >
        </android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip>
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment.xml-

```
<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1"
    android:id="@+id/main_table" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</TableLayout>
```

[image]

I want this header image at the top before tab.How can I achieve this?

[image]

I want this type of view.

Comment: Add this android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" properties to ViewPager.

Comment: @HareshChhelana- Its not working.Rather it has settled the table layout below.It had created a more gap between header and table layout.It didn't move the header above tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented by adding two lines in MainActivity which is extending FragmentActivity and in which we are setting our tab.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);  // To hide the app icon
ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.MyImage));
```

Comment: Pikhwal- its working fine. But when I m running my app in android device then this image is showing below tabs.